# GCM Notification shows JSON message

Tags: java, android, json, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

Im facing a problem of creating GCM notification. By default it is showing message in JSON form.

I want to wrap my JSON and only want to show some message let say 'You got new message' in notifications, but when any user click on notification then other information JSON etc should be available to client application.

Built GCM server application in Java and running on tomcat.

I followed official GCM website tutorial and their demo client/server apps.

[Update]:

```
Sender sender = new Sender(Constants.SENDER_ID);            
androidTargets.add(MY_DEVICE_ID);

Message message = new Message.Builder()
            .collapseKey("GCM_Message")
            .timeToLive(30)
            .delayWhileIdle(true)
            .addData("message", msg)
            .build();          

MulticastResult result = sender.send(message, androidTargets, 3);

System.out.println("GCM message sent");
if (result.getResults() != null) {
    int canonicalRegId = result.getCanonicalIds();
    if (canonicalRegId != 0) {  

    }
} else {
    int error = result.getFailure();
    System.out.println("Broadcast failure: " + error);
}
```

while 'message' is json string.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: show us what have you tried so far!

Comment: @goonerdroid kindly see update, mentioned code to send GCM from GCM server

Answer (score 0):

Pass your subject string to setContentTitle(subject),
you can check this code snippet  it may help you.

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) parametes.context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent intent = null;
        intent = new Intent(parametes.context, MainActivity.class);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                parametes.context, 0, intent, 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                parametes.context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon)
                .setContentTitle("My Subject Line here.")
                .setAutoCancel(true);


        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        parametes.mNotificationManager.notify(
                CheckInboxWithCountParams.NOTIFICATION_ID,
                mBuilder.getNotification());
```